# In what Javascript file "abp.services.app" is defined?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am integrating my own template to ASP.NET Boilerplate and now I am getting JavaScript errors.

```
(function() {
    $(function() {
        var _userService = abp.services.app.user; <-- ERROR HERE
    })
});
```

In what Javascript file "abp.services.app" is defined? I must be missing to include one of the Javascript file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's defined dynamically when you include `AbpServiceProxies/GetAll` like
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/blob/master/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebMpa/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml#L125 (this is for ASP.NET MVC 5.x).