# Use abp.services in JavaScript in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, aspnetboilerplate

I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555472/in-what-javascript-file-abp-services-app-is-defined/45559769#45559769) was asked before, but my question is about using `abp.services` methods in JavaScript directly.

Suppose I have:

```
public interface ISecurityAppService : IApplicationService
{
    List<PacsUser_C_Extented> GetAll();
}

public class SecurityAppService : ApplicationService, ISecurityAppService
{
    public List<PacsUser_C_Extented> GetAll()
    {
        // ...
        return allUsers;
    }
}
```

All the boilerplate services will be registered nicely as:

```
public class Global : AbpWebApplication<ImmenseWebModule>
{
    protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Application_Start(sender, e);
    }
}
```

As the `ASP.NET Boilerplate` documentation said, to be able to use the auto-generated services, you should include needed scripts in your page like:

```
<script src="~/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/angularjs/abp.ng.js"></script>
<script src="~/api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?type=angular"></script>
```

I know the second line says to use `angular` controller, but I change it to:

```
<script src="~/api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?v=@(Clock.Now.Ticks)">script>
```

...still nothing works.

When I want to use `getAll` in an ASP.NET Web Form's JavaScript code, it gives me:

> abp.service is not defined

So how can I use `getAll` or another method in `SecurityAppService` in the script element `<script>...</script>` — not Angular?

Thanks in advance.

## Update

When I use an Angular controller and MVC partial view like:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app');
    var controllerId = 'sts.views.security.list';
    app.controller(controllerId, [
        '$scope', 'abp.services.remotesystem.security',
        function ($scope, securityService) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.localize = abp.localization.getSource('ImmenseSystem');
            vm.users = [];
            vm.refreshUserList = function () {
                abp.ui.setBusy( // Set whole page busy until getTasks completes
                    null,
                    securityService.getAll().success(function (data) {
                        vm.users = data;
                        abp.notify.info(vm.localize('UserListLoaded'));
                    })
                );
            };
            vm.refreshUserList();
        }
    ]);
})();
```

I am able to use that function.
But I want to use that in JavaScript in ASP.NET Web Form pages.

Comment: `abp.service is not defined` → Did you forget the `s` in `abp.services`?

Comment: @arron No `s` were missed , I tried `abp.services`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved it by a simple way as the below steps...

1- Run project and use that boilerplate services by Angular and Partial view (MVC)
    like Update section in question.

2- After running and redirecting to a view, I went to `View page source` and see the dependencies scripts .

3- I copied the below scripts source to a page:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="Abp/Framework/scripts/utils/ie10fix.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/sweetalert/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/others/spinjs/spin.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/others/spinjs/jquery.spin.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-utils.min.js"></script>
<script src="Abp/Framework/scripts/abp.js"></script>
<script src="Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.toastr.js"></script>
<script src="Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.blockUI.js"></script>
<script src="Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.spin.js"></script>
<script src="Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.sweet-alert.js"></script>
<script src="Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/angularjs/abp.ng.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?v=636475780135774228"></script>
<script src="api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?type=angular&amp;v=636475780135774228"></script>
<script src="AbpScripts/GetScripts?v=636475780135774228" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and use `getAll` method like:

```
<script>
    var securityService = abp.services.remotesystem.security;
    securityService.getAll().done(function (data) {
        for (var i in data)
            console.log(data[i].username);
    });
</script>
```

I think the important staff to use auto-generated services is :

```
<script src="api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?v=636475780135774228"></script>
<script src="api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?type=angular&amp;v=636475780135774228"></script>
<script src="AbpScripts/GetScripts?v=636475780135774228" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Okay done, But I think some of scripts are unnecessary.

Comment: Only `<script src="api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?v=636475780135774228"></script>` seems required. But you say it doesn't work and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

you are injecting abp.services.remotesystem.security.
so you can use this namespace to access the functions. open chrome console and write **abp.services.remotesystem.security** you will see the functions

Answer (score 0):

AssetApplicationService must be implemented by IApplicationService and then check your module load correctly and add correct dependencies in other modules like this.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157094/aspnet-boilerplate-aspnetzero-dependency-injection/51379631#51379631). It's worked for me.